# Sort posts by meta value with get method

Tags: order, pre-get-posts

I have custom post type with meta values added by Advanced Custom Fields. I want to sort posts with get method by this meta and by post_date.

I make some code but it is works strange way - it didn't add opportunity to sort posts by meta, but just make any 'orderby' sorted by meta. So when I write in browser something like www.mysite.com/archive/?orderby=post_date it still sort it only by meta.

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // do not modify queries in the admin
    if( is_admin() ) {

        return $query;

    }


    // only modify queries for 'text' post type
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'text' ) {

        // allow the url to alter the query
        if( isset($_GET['orderby']) ) {

            $query->set('orderby',  'meta_value_num');  
            $query->set('meta_key', 'text_date');
            $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 


        } 

    }

    // return
    return $query;

}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually using the `$_GET['orderby']`-value anywhere. What you're doing in your code is ordering by the `text_date`-meta value, always. If you want to order by date by default, and when `$_GET['orderby']` is set to default orderby-values or if `$_GET['orderby_meta']` is set, order by those instead you need to do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['orderby']){
    $query->set('orderby', sanitize_key($_GET['orderby']);  
    $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 
} else if (isset($_GET['orderby_meta']){
    $query->set('orderby',  'meta_value_num');  
    $query->set('meta_key', 'text_date');
    $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanx for this answer. By default I want order by date, but i want to have opportunity to order them also by meta value.

Comment: Alright – date ordering is probably default, so you can remove the `else`-statement from my answer, and that should allow you to order by a meta value where that is needed (for example `text_date`), if that's what you meant?

Comment: Nearly!
Only last moment. So when i make something like orderby=title - wp thinks that i mean meta key "title" but not normal meaning of that variable. How can i handle with it?

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer - you'll need to use different `$_GET`-variables for meta keys and for regular orderby-keys.

Comment: may be i can make some if statement only for "text_date" something like

if (isset($_GET['orderby'] == 'text_date')

?

Comment: if (isset($_GET['orderby']) && $_GET['orderby'] == 'text_date') - works for me

Comment: Sure, that would also work.